# Automatic failover between internet connections

Tags: windows, networking

I have two different internet connections – one is starting with `192.168.1.1` to `192.168.1.254` and another is starting with `192.168.2.1`.

Is it possible to have my computers fail over from one network to the other if the internet connection drops?

Some PCs have their IP configured with 192.168.1.1, and some with 192.168.2.1.

Comment: merging them: does it solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there's not a good automatic solution for this on Windows. I know that some applications from NIC vendors like Broadcom have applications for their NIC’s that could do what you ask for. If that’s not applicable I think you have to solve it with scripts that changes metrics or routes.

Since you have several computers I suggest that you solve this in a Router/NAT-gateway, there are several affordable off the shelf solutions. Dual WAN is the function you’re looking for. Also open source firewalls like pfsense have dual WAN capabilities if you can and are willing to set that up.